# Use schedules in Laravel settings

Tags: php, laravel

I have profiles that run on a schedule, in the settings of each profile there is a period of **everyFiveMinutes** type, Then in the kernel I use this

```
$tasks = ProfileExchange::where('active', true)->whereNotNull('frequency')->get();

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $frequency = $task->frequency;
    $schedule->command(RunExchange::class, ['--id' => $task->id])
        ->runInBackground()
        ->$frequency();
}
```

but if in setup I want to use this `at('13:00')` then I get an error, help me fix it

Comment: And what is the error you get? Search for that error on the internet, you'll find posts with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because a value of `at('13:00')` in `$task->frequency` will become this in your code:

```
$schedule->command(RunExchange::class, ['--id' => $task->id])
        ->runInBackground()
        ->at('13:00')();
```

It's a bad idea to run code from your database like this anyway, it opens you up to potential code injection.

If I were you, I'd change `$task->frequency` to be either `"every 5 minutes"`, `"every 10 minutes"` and other similar options, then if-else or switch-case for them in your code:

```
if($task->frequency == "every 5 minutes") {
    $schedule->command(RunExchange::class, ['--id' => $task->id])
        ->runInBackground()
        ->everyFiveMinutes();
} else if 
...
```

Then you can do a regex check for whether `$task->frequency` is a time, and use `at` to run it at that time:

```
...
else if(preg_match("\d?\d:\d\d", $task->frequency)) {
    $schedule->command(RunExchange::class, ['--id' => $task->id])
        ->runInBackground()
        ->at($task->frequency);
}
```

You'll need to change how you store the time in your database too, it will have to be `13:00` instead of `at('13:00')`